# $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is discontinues.

$|x-x_0|<\delta$, for $\delta>0$

$|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_0}|=|\frac{x_0-x}{xx_0}|<\frac{|-\delta|}{xx_0}$

I know the function is discontinues at 0 but can I actually prove it without setting an interval?

**Question**:

Is this the way to prove it? If not. Why? How?

How do I finish the proof?

Comment: It is continuous over its domain.  It is not continuous over the real numbers.

Comment: Discontinuous at where?

Comment: $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$ is not discontinuous at $x=0$ because $x=0$ is not in the domain of the function and continuity is defined only for $x$ in the domain so that $f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x)$ is not defined at 0, by definition it is discontinuous. You don't need to use intervals to demonstrate this.

If, instead, you are trying to show that this is not a removable discontinuity, you can use a similar proof structure to what you've started. That is, you can show that if we define $f(0) = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is still discontinuous at 0, because for all $\delta > 0$, for all $\epsilon > 0$, you can find $x_{0} \neq 0$ with $|x_{0} - 0| < \delta$ such that $|f(x_{0}) - f(0)| > \epsilon$.

Comment: Is this correct $|\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{1}{0}|=\infty>\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: No, $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined. However, if we let $f(0) = c$, we can always find an $x_{0}$ such that $|frac{1}{x_{0}} - c| > \epsilon$, because as $x_{0}$ approaches 0, $\frac{1}{x_{0}}$ approaches $\infty$. We cannot say it equals $\infty$, though.

Comment: In the definition of "discontinuous at" that I'm familiar with, it is required that the point belongs to the domain of the function. "$\sin$ is discontinuous at my left shoe" is a sentence that simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, @DanielFischer I agree. In answering this, I assumed $0$ was in the domain of the function (and $f(0)$ undefined), because the original poster was attempting to show $f$ is discontinuous at 0. On $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, $f$ is indeed continuous.

Comment: I strongly disagree as @Daniel Fisher does, at this answer "since $f$ is not defined at 0, by definition it is discontinuous at O" for the reason Daniel has given. This answer should not be validated.

Answer (score 0):

Even without studying the domain of definition, if $f$ were continuous then it would verify intermediate value theorem.

But $f(-1)=-1<0$ and $f(1)=1>0$ so there would exists $c\in]-1,1[$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Since this equation has no solution, then $f$ is discontinuous.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem says something about continuous functions on an interval. $f \colon [-2,-1] \cup [1,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x$ is continuous, but doesn't have the intermediate value property.

Comment: Taken as is, the OP statement means "*is $f$ continuous between any two points where it is defined*" ? . With answer no, since there exists an interval where it does not verify IVT. Continuity is always defined relatively to an interval, so this naturally implies that the domain of definition of $f$ should be connected. I'm curious about your definition of $f$ continuous over a disconnected domain.

Comment: A function $f \colon X \to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, is continuous if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ for all open $U \subset Y$. It is continuous at $x_0 \in X$ if for every neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$, the preimage $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: I see where you want to go, but that's only to try to add more confusion. Here the underlying spaces $X,Y$ are $\mathbb R$ with its usual topology. So if I take $U=]-2,2[$ open of $Y$ then $V=f^{-1}(U)=]-2,-1]\cup [1,2[$ is not open thus $f$ not continuous. But setting $X=D_f$ as a **subset** keeps the topology of $\mathbb R$ (where $V$ not open) not the subspace topology of $D_f$ as a **subspace** (where $V$ is open), because if we do this then we artificially make discontinuous functions in the usual topology become continuous.

Comment: $X$ is the domain of $f$, which is in this case a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$. And it carries its subspace topology (which is the topology induced by the standard metric). It simply doesn't make sense to talk about continuity of a function at points outside its domain.